# Update block arguemnts in xml file (Recommended way not working)

Tags: layout, blocks, magento-2.0

Magento 2.0.2

*File :-* **vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml**

**block :-**

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Attributes" name="product.attributes" as="additional" template="product/view/attributes.phtml" group="detailed_info">
  <arguments>
     <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">
        More Information
     </argument>
  </arguments>
</block>
```

I am overwriting this block in my module with same file name like this (by action method) and it is working:-

```
<referenceBlock name="product.attributes">
    <action method="setTitle">
       <argument name="title" xsi:type="string">Product Details</argument>
    </action>
</referenceBlock>
```

But when i updated this title by this below method (argument menthod) it is not working:-

```
<referenceBlock name="product.attributes">
    <arguments>
       <argument name="title" xsi:type="string">Product Details</argument>
    </arguments>
</referenceBlock>
```

So, my question here is that why it is working by first method, as it is mentioned in documentation that it is not a recommended way to modify block arguments
[link](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-manage.html#layout_markup_modify-block)

Answer (score 0):

Argument method working something like this

```
<referenceBlock class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Attributes" name="product.attributes" as="additional" template="product/view/attributes.phtml" group="detailed_info">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="title" xsi:type="string">Product Details</argument>
    </arguments>
</referenceBlock>
```